# Measure on non -discrete locally compact group

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure

I See the following statement

let $G$ be a locally compact group with a fixed left Haar
measure $\lambda$ If $G$ is not discrete
, for all $x \in U$,  there is an open relatively compact neighborhood $O$ of the identity element of $G$ with $O^2 \subseteq U$. We can choose a sequence $(O_n)$ of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $O$ such that $\bar O_n$ is compact and
$λ(O_n) < 2^{−n}$, for all $n \geq 1$.

I'm stuck here

> We can choose a sequence $(O_n)$ of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $O$ such that $\bar O_n$ is compact and
> $λ(O_n) < 2^{−n}$, for all $n \geq 1$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You say "for all $x\in U$", but the part that comes after doesn't mention $x$. Also what is $U$?

Comment: @ halrankard, $U$ is neighborhood of $x$

Comment: Ok but the sentence still says nothing else about $x$. So what role does $x$ play in this situation? Also there must be some other assumptions on $U$ in order to say that it contains an open neighborhood of the identity.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the source of this. The sentence "for all $x\in U$, there is an open relatively compact neighborhood $O$ of the identity element of $G$ with $O^2\subseteq U$" is confusing. It's like saying "for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a prime number $p$ greater than $100$".

Comment: Suppose $G$ is not discrete. Then there exist a relatively  compact neighborhood $O$ and a sequence $(O_n)$ of pairwise disjoint open subset of $O$ such that $$\lambda(O_n)<2^{-n}$$ for all $n\geq1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim 1.** Given an open neighborhood $O$ of the identity in a nondiscrete locally compact group, construct a sequence $O_{1},O_{2},\ldots$ of *nonempty* pairwise disjoint open sets contained in $O$ such that $\lambda(O_{n})<2^{-n}$.

(Note that you must want each $O_{n}$ to be nonempty or the situation is trivial. Also if you know $O$ is relatively compact then each $O_{n}$ has compact closure too.)

**Proof:** It suffices to fix $\epsilon>0$, and find nonempty disjoint open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $O$ such that $\lambda(U)<\epsilon$. Since if this is possible then the sets $O_{n}$ can be constructed by induction.

Nondiscreteness of $G$ means that around any point we can find an open set of arbitrarily small measure.

So start with $O$ and choose two distinct $x,y\in O$ (these exist since $O$ is not a singleton). Choose $U$ and $V$ pairwise disjoint open sets with $x\in U$ and $y\in V$. We can intersect with $O$ to assume $U$ and $V$ are subsets of $O$. By the nondiscreteness property we can further intersect $U$ with an open neighborhood of $x$ of measure less than $\epsilon$, and thus ensure $\lambda(U)<\epsilon$.

Comment: @thank you so much halrankard this is good answer

Comment: you're welcome!